# Include JS into JS for Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How to include JS into another JS file for chrome extension?

I have these 3 files:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Block request",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
       "js": ["content_script.js"]
}],

  "permissions": [
      "webRequest",
      "webRequestBlocking",
      "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

**content_script.js**

```
include 'myfile.js';
include 'https://sample.com/sample.js';
```

**myfile.js** (in chrome extension pack)

```
if (window.location.hostname === "www.sample.com") {
    console.log("Hi console");
}
```

**sample.js** (file exists in my host)

```
if (window.location.hostname === "www.demo.com") {
    console.log("My message from Space");
}
```

I know `content_script.js` is Not correct; I've tested some code but I didn't get any correct result.
How Can I solve this issue?

Comment: Define several content script sections and use the site patterns in `”matches”` instead of one master script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

> The list of JavaScript files to be injected into matching pages. These
>   are injected in the order they appear in this array.

```
"js": ["content_script.js", "myfile.js", "sample.js"]
```

Comment: Thank you @Nathan; It works fine when I use JS in my extension package, But When I add JS file from my host into extension I got an error on extension upload and extension doesn't work.
How Can I solve this?

Comment: Hey, sorry, not to sure what you mean?